# Why are some tablets Telmisartan, Amlodipine and Hydrochlorothiazide bilayered and some are not?

Tags: medications, drug-metabolism, drug-interactions

I recently saw that some brands of Telmisartan, Amlodipine and Hydrochlorothiazide tablets are bilayered and some are not?

On Googling I found [this](https://www.thomasnet.com/articles/other/all-about-the-bilayer-tablet-manufacturing-process/#:%7E:text=Bilayered%20tablet%20technology%20separates%20two,adding%20an%20inert%20intermediate%20layer.)

> Bilayered tablet technology separates two incompatible substances in
> which one layer is immediate release as a loading dose, and the second
> layer is controlled/sustained release as a maintenance dose. Two
> incompatible drugs can also be formulated into a bilayer tablet by
> adding an inert intermediate layer.

Also [this](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20060110450A1/en) where it says that both telmisartan and amlodipine are instantly released. But then it uses two different methods for it. Why?

> A bilayer tablet comprises a first layer formulated for instant
> release of the angiotensin II receptor antagonist telmisartan from a
> dissolving tablet matrix and a second layer formulated for instant
> release of the calcium channel blocker amlodipine from a
> disintegrating or eroding tablet matrix.

But none of the above mentioned drugs are incompatible with each other. Moreover all of them are often used once per day.

So I don't see the rationale of using a bilayer for incompatibility or controlled release.

Why is this being done by some brands?

**Bilayered tablets**
[image]

**Non Bilayered tablets**

[image]

Comment: Where does the quote come from? You need to add a link to quotes you add to questions.

Comment: @CareyGregory ok, I'll edit it

Comment: @CareyGregory done

Comment: I think your source simply used a poor choice of language. "Incompatible" isn't the word whoever wrote that was looking for. I suspect simply "different" would be the correct word.

Comment: @CareyGregory yes but then why are most of these tablets bilayered as opposed to siimply mixed.

Comment: If one of them is extended release those are usually very different formulas and perhaps can't be mixed.

Comment: @CareyGregory if that is so why are some compaines selling not bilayered tablets. Refer to the second image

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I would imagine the science of engineering modern drugs isn't a simple matter and only someone with experience in that field is going to be able to answer this.

Comment: Actually, looking at those photos again I realize you can't really be sure whether the second drug is bilayered or not. Is that a labeling requirement in the country where you bought them?

Comment: @CareyGregory I checked them personally by opening it. They aren't bilayered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are good reasons why some drugs are bilayered. A company could decide to produce a bilayered drug formulation for the same drug if it's necessary to produce a formulation in which the drug in one of the layers is released instantly while the drug in the second layer is released gradually to produce prolonged effect, sustained release. This helps to reduce the frequency of administeration. By reducing the frequency of administeration a drug that is administered every 8 hours can be administered every 24 hours or so. This enhances Patient compliance.
Two compatible/incompatible drugs can be made Into a bilayered formulation. Clinical experience has shown that patient compliance can be improved by reducing the quantity of drugs that is administered. Instead of taking two or three different tablets to treat certain disease condition/conditions, one formulation  containing  the whole drugs can be taken. Also some disorders, such as hypertension, are better managed using a combination of drugs that act through different mechanisms. The rationale behind this is beyond the scope of this question.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344267062_Bilayer_tablets_A_developing_novel_drug_delivery_system